# How to break "for" loop in python and pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, adafruit

We're currently programming a robot using pygame lib, python, raspberryPI, and adafruit motor hat. Here is example of what we do to increase the speed of the motors from 0 to 100:

```
for i in range(100):
    motor.run(i)
```

This code is inside definitions for moving forward, backward and around and it is used when a keyboard button is pressed. However, we want to interrupt the "for" loop when the KEY is release.

Comment: You can break out of a loop using the `break` keyword.  You'll need some type of `if ...` check for detecting the key press/release state.

Comment: Don't forget to google around before asking a question.  I just googled "python break out of a for loop" and got: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

You actually hit the solution on the head with the word 'break':

```
for i in range(100):
    motor.run(i)
    if ...: #key is released
        break
```